# how to get records from multiple tables using criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate-criteria

```
StuPersonal table-sno,stu_name,gender,FRID;
StuDegree table-sno,degree,dtype,regno,col_name,stP(FRID).
```

the above is my tables definition(OnetoOne) relationship.
My pojo classes are

```
@Entity
public class StuPersonal {
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID") 
private int sno;

@Column(name="NAME") 
private String stu_name;
private int name_verify=0;

@Column(name="GENDER")
private String gender;

@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="FRID")
private List<StuDegree> StuDegree;
@Id
private String FRID;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class StuDegree {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
@Column(name="sNO")        
private int sno;

@Column(name="DEGREE")
private String degree;

@Column(name="DEGREE_TYPE")
private String dtype;
@Column(name="COLLEGE_NAME") 
private String col_name;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="FRID")
private StuPersonal stP;
```

and my main class is

```
Criteria criteria= s. createCriteria(StuDegree.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("col_name","PSYEC"));
List<StuDegree> colname =(List<StuDegree>) criteria.list();
```

I used above lines to get records from Studegree table;

```
for (Iterator iterator = colname.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{
   StuDegree stdeg= (StuDegree) iterator.next();
   {
     Criteria criteria1= s.createCriteria(StuPersonal.class);
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("stdeg.getFRID()","StuPersonal.getFRID()"));
     List<StuPersonal> stuper=(List<StuPersonal>) criteria1.list();
     System.out.println(stuper.size());
   }
}
```

I used above codes for taking records from StuPersonal tables using FRID from Studegree table, Is it right? And it is not working...Pl advice...

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You can't use a OneToOne on an attribute of type List. A List contains many elements. So it's obviously a OneToMany.

Answer (score 1):

Change your relationship like below.

change

```
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="FRID")
private List<StuDegree> StuDegree;
```

to

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="FRID")
private List<StuDegree> StuDegree;
```

and your Criteria is like this. It will fetch the StuPersonal based on the StuDegree sno's.

```
Integer snos[] = {1,2,3};
Criteria criteria = s.createCriteria(StuPersonal.class, "sp");
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
criteria.createAlias("sp.StuDegree","sd");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("sd.sno", snos));
List<StuPersonal> stuper= criteria1.list();
```